# Set title of a span based on first child text content

Tags: jquery, children

i tried:

```
$('span.tag').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('title', '').prop('title', function(){$(this).children('li:first').text();});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('span.tag').attr('title', function(){
    return $(this).find('li:first').text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

why so complex? it's just simple

```
$('span.tag').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).find('li:first').text());
});
```